# Type-level constraint on HList, extract function domain

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am writing a combinator that takes in an `HList` of `Option[A] :: Option[AA] :: Option[AAA]...` etc.

It also takes a function`f` of type `A,AA, AAA,... =>  U`. And it returns `U`. How do I encode the type signature for my combinator? I need to assume my `A, AA, AAA` are also Monoids so if my options are `None`, I can call on Monoid zero to create values for `f`. I am new to shapeless so thank you!

This is what I have so far, but I am missing a lot of constraints.

1. Every element of `H` is an `Option[A], Option[AA], ...`
2. `A, AA, AAA` are all Monoids.
3. The `HList` D is just
   the same as `H` without the Option.

```
def combinator[H <: HList, D <: HList, U](in: H, f : D => U) : U =
  f(in map { 
    case None : Option[A] => implicitly[Monoid[A]].zero
    case Some(v) => v
  })
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by `AA` and `AAA`?

Comment: These are free types, universally quantified.

Comment: Except the part that they are implicit Monoid. Sorry I should have clarified before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  import shapeless.{HList, ::, HNil, Id, Poly1}
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Comapped, LiftAll, Mapper, NatTRel}
  import cats.Monoid
  import cats.syntax.option._
  import cats.instances.int._
  import cats.instances.string._
  import cats.instances.double._

  object monoidPoly extends Poly1 {
    implicit def cse[A: Monoid]: Case.Aux[Option[A], A] = at {
      case None => implicitly[Monoid[A]].empty
      case Some(v) => v
    }
  }

  def combinator[H <: HList, D <: HList, U](in: H, f: D => U)(
    implicit
//    comapped: Comapped.Aux[H, Option, D],
//    natTRel: NatTRel[H, Option, D, Id],
//    liftAll: LiftAll[Monoid, D],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[monoidPoly.type, H, D]
  ): U =
    f(in map monoidPoly)

  combinator(1.some :: none[String] :: 2.0.some :: HNil, (_ : Int :: String :: Double :: HNil).toString)
  // "1 ::  :: 2.0 :: HNil"
```

Comment: This is awesome, why did you comment out the implicits on combinator?

Comment: @rausted You can uncomment them but they are not necessary in this particular case. In this particular case if there is a `Mapper` for our specific `Poly` then there are `Comapped`, `NatTRel`, `LiftAll`.